# jQuery UI Autocomplete parsing data

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, autocomplete

I'm trying to add autocomplete to my search input:

```
jQuery( "#search_word" ).autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.getJSON("/search/auto-complete", { k: $('#search_word').val() },
      response);
  },
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    var item = ui.item;
    jQuery(this).val(item.value);
    if (item.url) {
      window.location.href = item.url;
      return false;
    }
    var page_name = jQuery(this).attr('data-page-name');
    submitCategory();
  }
});
```

But as you can probably guess, I couldn't. Some extra fields are returned if they have the same keyword.

I created a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/wuktx4xr/

Nobody has to fix it for me. I just want to know how can I parse the data and show a response.

The data that my source callback returns looks like this:

```
{
  "keyword": ["zippo","zippo lighter","zippo warmer"],

  "store":{
    "storeId":44922, 
    "storeName":"Zippo", 
    "storeTitle":"Zippo", 
    "storeLogoUrl":"http://images.server.com/d/store/d_44922.jpg",
    "storeSlug":"zippo"
  }
}
```

`keyword` includes autocomplete options. `store` isn't always populated. If it is, I want to include `storeTitle` as the last value in my autocomplete options.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle isn't going to work for a couple reasons. One, if you check the console, there appears to be a syntax error. Two, that url for your AJAX call isn't going to work.

That aside, this is what I think you're looking to do:

```
$('#search_word').autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.getJSON(
        '/search/auto-complete',
        { k: request.term },
        function(data) {
          var options = data.keyword;

          if ( data.store ) {
            options.push(data.store.storeTitle);
          }

          response(options);
        }
    );
  },

  select: function( event, ui ) {
    var userSelected = ui.item.value;
    // do something with userSelected value
  }
});
```

Notice, in particular, how the `response` argument is used with the `getJSON` callback. `response`, as explained in [the docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source), expects an array of strings, so use a `data` property appropriate to your backend response.

For a demonstration that mocks a remote call, see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/klenwell/mborem1p/

Comment: Thanks for reply and edits. Actually, my confusion is about my JSON data. "keyword" is an array but "store" is an object. So, i don't know how can i parse them in one $.each function. Because my goal is here, using "keyword"'s and "store"'s values all together(if store value returns). [my expectation](http://jsfiddle.net/wuktx4xr/6/)

Comment: @linepisode I've modified the question and my answer to reflect the additional information you provided. This doesn't necessarily get you all the way there but it should get you close enough. I don't think it's possible to include an image in the autocomplete options. There may be clever ways to rig that up, but it would be beyond the scope of this question.